# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'get_reset_password_token'

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I have been following the guide at https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-x-email-support to implement a password reset feature in my Flask app.

My error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\David PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\David PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\David PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\David PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "C:\Users\David PC\Desktop\VS Code Python\Flask Site\app.py", line 691, in passwordreset
    EmailSender(form.email.data, "Password reset", {"url": url_for("reset_password", token=user.get_reset_password_token(), _external=True)}, 6)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'get_reset_password_token'
```

My route view is:

```
@app.route('/passwordreset', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def passwordreset():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('profile'))
    form = ResetPasswordRequestForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = mycol.find_one({"email": form.email.data})
        if user:
            EmailSender(form.email.data, "Password reset", {"url": url_for("reset_password", token=user.get_reset_password_token(), _external=True)}, 6)
            return redirect(url_for('homepage'))
        flash('If an account with this email was registered please check your email.')
    return render_template('reset_password_request.html', title='Reset Password', form=form)
```

And my User class is:

```
class User(UserMixin):
    def __init__(self, user_json):
        self.user_json = user_json

    def get_id(self):
        object_id = self.user_json.get('_id')
        return str(object_id)

    def get_reset_password_token(self, expires_in=600):
        return jwt.encode(
            {'reset_password': self.id, 'exp': time() + expires_in},
            app.config['SECRET_KEY'], algorithm='HS256')

    @staticmethod
    def verify_reset_password_token(token):
        try:
            id = jwt.decode(token, app.config['SECRET_KEY'],
                            algorithms=['HS256'])['reset_password']
        except:
            return
        return User.query.get(id)
```

I have a sneaking suspicion I am missing something basic but I cannot seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: well, apparently `mycol.find_one({"email": form.email.data})` returns a dictionary instead of your `User` class

Comment: Lol. Indeed. I *think* I fixed it by wrapping my pymongo query in `User(query)`. Now apparently jwt doesn't have an encode attribute. But that is another problem for another day. Can you post answer and I'll accept.

Comment: not entirely sure what to answer there, I was just guessing around, besides I don't know how to actually fix it, I just figured what caused it so yeah...

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @Matiss, I had to wrap my pymongo DB query in my `User` class.

`user = User(mycol.find_one({"email": form.email.data}))`

This was the fix to the attribute error.